# Phrases to cheer people up?

Tags: phrase-request

What are the best phrases to use to cheer up other people who are going through difficulties or frustrated by failure?

All I can think of:

> Cheer up!

Is this even right in the above context?

Answer (score 1):

These ones also work: *bounce back, pull through, get over*.

> — *You didn't cook well but you can always **bounce back**!*
>   — *Don't let this win you, you just need to **pull through**.*
>   — *I know you're sick but I'm sure you can **get over it**.*

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cheer%20up)

a few phrases:

> buck up
>
> buoy up
>
> perk up

Though your question was only related to cheering them up, you could also offer words of support/encouragement such as:

> hang in there
>
> tough it out
>
> never say die